# Django - pip grappelli not on the good Python install

Tags: python, django, pip, python-2.7, django-grappelli

I'm using Django 1.3 with Python 2.7 in Ubuntu.
Trying to install [django-grappelli](http://sehmaschine.github.com/django-grappelli/) with pip

```
$ pip install django-grappelli
```

It apparently installs for Python 2.6 (the distribution version)

> Requirement already satisfied: django-grappelli in /usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages

Maybe because I installed pip with apt-get ?
How can I install grappelli for my Python 2.7 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python 2.7 packages should be in a different place then Python 2.6 packages. For you then `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/` I think.

You can tell PIP to install into specific location by:

```
pip install --install-option="--prefix=/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/" django-grapelli
```

You can also use version specific commands to do the installation.

```
pip-2.7 install django-grapelli
```

If `pip-2.7` command is not found use `easy_install-2.7` to install pip.

Comment: Actually easy_install installs for Python 2.7 (without using easy_install-2.7) but now it seems more inclined to use pip, that's why I am using it.

Comment: Yes, pip seems to be the future. I have not had this problem myself but I imagine that you had pip installed for 2.6 at first so it has to be reconfigured. See if pip points to the right python version itself.

Answer (score 0):

I have installed pip with Synaptic so it has been installed for the repos python version (2.6).
To correct this problem I had to uninstall pip with Synaptic and install it with easy_install

```
$ sudo apt-get --purge remove python-pip
$ sudo easy_install pip
$ sudo pip install django-grappelli
```